# Tried to load unspecified class: Date (Psych::DisallowedClass) while updating the ruby 2.5 to 3.2.1 and rails version from 5.2.2 to 7.0.4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

```html
 Exiting
scheduler-2-backend                   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/class_loader.rb:99:in `find': Tried to load unspecified class: Date (Psych::DisallowedClass)
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/class_loader.rb:28:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from (eval):2:in `date'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb:66:in `tokenize'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:65:in `deserialize'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:130:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Scalar'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:347:in `block in revive_hash'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each_slice'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `revive_hash'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:169:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:347:in `block in revive_hash'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each_slice'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `revive_hash'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:169:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:320:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych.rb:334:in `safe_load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych.rb:369:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:103:in `initialize'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:60:in `new'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:60:in `instance'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:48:in `load!'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/app/models/konfig.rb:9:in `<class:Konfig>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/app/models/konfig.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/app/models/agent_config.rb:6:in `<class:AgentConfig>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/app/models/agent_config.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/app/admin/agent_configs.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:124:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:124:in `block in load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/error.rb:44:in `capture'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:124:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:116:in `block in load!'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:116:in `each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:116:in `load!'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:142:in `routes'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-3.0.0/lib/active_admin.rb:75:in `routes'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/config/routes.rb:81:in `block in <top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:428:in `instance_exec'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:428:in `eval_block'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/config/routes.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `block in load_paths'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `load_paths'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:24:in `reload!'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:38:in `block in updater'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `execute'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:158:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from /src/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from bin/rails:3:in `load'
scheduler-2-backend                   |     from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Using bootboot gem I am dual booting the application while running in the ruby 3.2.1 and rails 7.0.4.2. I am facing this issue while starting the container in docker.

**Tried diff solutions provided on internet ie:**
**use in application.rb**
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Date, Time, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone]

**use in application.rb**
config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load = true

In application I am using Blueprinter gem to serialize upgraded this gem to version 0.25.3 still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I just replied your error, you have to set to the Disallowed class settings the specific class you want to use. For example `Symbol`, `Date`, `Time`, etc. `Date` in your case.

Be awared of the security implications of allowing these classes to be parsed.

In your `application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [
      Date,
      DateTime,
      ...
    ]
```

You might find other classes when you perform this fix, remember to restart your server after changing the `application.rb` file.